# Delete the duplicate order number query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, duplicates, oracle-apex

I have a question about deleting 2 duplicate numbers in my system. The issue is when the user creates an order and doubles by clicking the "Submit" button. The system makes 2 orders with the same number, how can I solve this issue by deleting the duplicating and prevent the system from making 2 orders with the same number? Is there a query to solve this issue?

Thank you,

Comment: Please share the sample data and expected result. To prevent this from happening in future you can use Unique index on that column.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get into the situation where you need to delete duplicate orders.

1. Once they have clicked the submit button, disable the button so they cannot click it a second time. (If the submission could fail then either: catch the failure, display an appropriate error message and re-enable the button; or re-enable the button after a short delay).
2. Use a `UNIQUE` constraint (or index) on the table to prevent the insertion of a duplicate order.
3. Use a `MERGE` statement to insert the order so that a duplicate would update the previous order rather than trying to insert a second order.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to restrict duplicates like below

```
  If Not Exists(Select 1 from Your_Table Where [Number]=Value)
    Begin
    Insert Query
    End
```

And For Delete Duplicate Number

```
  ;With Cte as( 
       Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By [Number_Column] Order By [Number_Column])Rno,[Number_Column] From Your_Table
    )
    Delete From CTE where Rno>1
```

Like you can delete your Duplicates.